# server error coming while establishing login logout session in php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have taken help from a website and used most of their code. I understood the code but can't figure out the error.

//main_login.php

```
<html>
<title>User Login Form</title>
<head></head>
<body>
<form name="form1" method="post" action="newcheckLogin.php">
<td>
<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
<tr>
<td width="80">Username</td>
<td width="6">:</td>
<td width="300"><input name="myusername" type="text" id="myusername"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Password</td>
<td width="6">:</td>
<td><input name="mypassword" type="password" id="mypassword"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Login"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</form>
```

//newchecklogin.php- This is used to check user and querying db.

```
    <?php
    include("config.php");
    session_start();
    #echo "Check Login\n";
    ?>
    <html>
    <head><title></title>
    <form name="form2" method="post" action="Logout.php">
    <p align="right">
    <input type="submit" name="Logout" id=Logout" >
    </p>
    </form>
    </head>
    </html>
    <?php
    $myusername=stripslashes(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['myusername']));
    $mypassword=md5(stripslashes(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['mypassword'])));
    $sql="select jobid from jobs where userID='$myusername'";
    echo "Hey ".$myusername." ";
    $result=mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
    $row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
    $active=$row['active'];
    if(mysql_num_rows($result)==1){
            echo "Username and password found";
            session_register("myusername");            
            $_SESSION['login_user']=$myusername;           
            header("location:welcome.php");
    }
    else{
            $error="Your login Name or Password is invalid";
    }
    ?>
```

//welcome.php

```
<?php
include('lock.php');
include('newchecklogin.php');
?>
<body>
<h1>Hello <?php echo $login_session; ?></h1>
<?php
echo "<br>You have ".$mysql_num_rows($result)." jobs<br>";
echo "<table border=1 cellpadding=4><th>Job id</th><br>";
while ( $r = mysql_fetch_assoc($result) ) {
        echo "<tr><td>";
        echo $r['jobid']."</td></tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
?>
</body>
```

//lock.php

```
<?php
include('config.php');
session_start();
$user_check=$_Session['login_user'];
$ses_sql=mysql_query("select userID from jobs where userID='$user_check'");
$row=mysql_fetch_array($ses_sql);
$login_session=$row['userID'];
if(!isset($login_session)){
        header("Location:login.php");
}
?>
```

Please help and it would be great if someone can explain me again how to set up the session.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Comment: What does the error say?

Comment: And *what* error is it now? Is it related to the incorrect casing of the session variable? Then please look at the [manual examples on sessions](http://php.net/session)

Comment: And the error says... ?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that, you have named `lock.php` file, and you are trying to redirect `login.php` after trying to log.

Comment: @Alfabravo: The error says HTTP Error 500 (Internal server error).

Comment: Ok..After logging in, I redirect to lock.php. I have modified it.                                                                                                             So it should redirect to newchecklogin and from there to welcome.php.                                                        `                                                                                                                                      if(!isset($login_session)){
        header("Location:login.php");
}
else{
        header("Location:newchecklogin.php");
        
}`

Comment: Now an empty page comes..Lock.php..Not directing to newchecklogin. And I am still not able to figure out how to debug these empty white page errors?

Comment: after you login, what happens next?

Comment: What I did now, was redirected back to newchecklogin. commented lock.php completely. But now in checklogin it is entering into else loop that is invalid username

Comment: Now username is printing and not the result so I think I found out that I am not registering result variable in session only the username is getting registered. Here How to register $result var in session when its returning multiple rows? Do I need to put it in a loop?? How?

Comment: i think  $ r ow [ ' a c t i v e ' ] is empty, can u check

Comment: I commented that. And now Hey is only printing. Why the username is not printing. and the no. of rows is coming 0 .

Comment: are u posting from main_login.php to newchecklogin.php ?? if so, why do u have input fields in newchecklogin.php and ?

Comment: I am on my mobile, but I'll try to help you, if make everything clear to me

Comment: Are you talking about the input fields in html code in newchecklogin? That input is just a dummy button for logout. It does not do anything right now but will be used to expire session